# Programmatically store iOS contact which can completely update and unify with an existing contact if possible

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I am writing an application for my club that displays the contacts which are saved on a server in an app for iOS. I can already connect and display all the information and can save a contact to the iOS Address Book. The goal however is to have a contact there which uniquely links to the contact saved by my application so that i can later modify the contact to accurately update the information in it. Now  i know that iOS has unified contacts (so that you can link 2 contacts to form 1 unified contact). Is it possible to save to a application managed contact and have that contact merge/unify with an user created contact which a % of matching (e.g. matching based on given name and family name).

I already have:

```
import Contacts
import ContactsUI
```

and added an:

```
CNContactPickerDelegate
```

To manage my contacts to add i added a small class which contains the information of the users:

```
class Contact {
    var givenName : String?
    var familyName : String?
    var mobile : String?
    var email : String?
    var HouseNumber : String?
    var city : String?
    var postalcode : String?
    var street : String?
    var birthdate : NSDate?

    func addName(givenName : String) {
        self.givenName = givenName
    }

    func addFamilyName(familyName : String) {
        self.familyName = familyName
    }

    func addMobile(mobile : String) {
        self.mobile = mobile
    }

    func addHouseNumber(HouseNumber : String) {
        self.HouseNumber = HouseNumber
    }

    func addEmail(email : String) {
        self.email = email
    }

    func addCity(city : String) {
        self.city = city
    }

    func addPostal(postal : String) {
        self.postal = postal
    }

    func addStreet(street : String) {
        self.street = street
    }

    func addBirthday(birtday : NSDate) {
        self.birthday = birtday
    }

}
```

So when it comes to saving the contacts i use:

```
let cnContact = CNMutableContact()
cnContact.givenName = contact.givenName! // offcourse with if-let statements :-)
cnContact.familyName = contact.familyName!
cnContact.emailAddresses = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value email)]
//.... //
```

Finally store them using:

```
let store = CNContactStore()
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
saveRequest.addContact(cnContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
try! store.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
```

Now the way i can update records is to use the ContactsUI and update the selected contact. But i want to update everything programmatically and alter the contacts saved earlier by this app. Is there a way to achieve this?